# Vector field and its components

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

If I have a cartesian vector field just denoted $\mathbf{E}=\mathbf{E}(x,y,z)$ (e.g. a electric field), does it mean:
$$
\mathbf{E}(x,y,z)=x\mathbf{\hat{x}}+y\mathbf{\hat{y}}+z\mathbf{\hat{z}} \tag{1}
$$ 
or
$$\mathbf{E}(x,y,z)=x(x,y,z)\mathbf{\hat{x}}+y(x,y,z)\mathbf{\hat{y}}+
z(x,y,z)\mathbf{\hat{z}}\tag{2}
$$
or
$$\mathbf{E}(x,y,z)=E_x(x,y,z)\mathbf{\hat{x}}+E_y(x,y,z)\mathbf{\hat{y}}+
E_z(x,y,z)\mathbf{\hat{z}}\tag{3}
$$

Are there any differences? Any of them wrong?

Comment: (1) Here you have a very particular vector field, in (2) you have what could be named a more general vector field, where each component is a real funcion in three variables and all together form a real field $\;\Bbb R^3\to\Bbb R^3\;$ , Finally, (3) could be taken as a gradient since the notation $\;H_x\;$ and etc. usually denotes partial derivatives, though if you make clear the subindex just denotes the corresponding coordinate then it is fine....though dangerously confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Remark: As notation is quite subjective, that's how I see it. (Note that my point of view already disagrees with Don Antonio's one)

If we write them using the standard notation they appear as:
\begin{equation}E(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix} \tag{1}\end{equation}

\begin{equation}E(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}x(x,y,z)\\y(x,y,z)\\z(x,y,z)\end{pmatrix} \tag{2}\end{equation}

\begin{equation}E(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}E_x(x,y,z)\\E_y(x,y,z)\\E_z(x,y,z)\end{pmatrix} \tag{3}\end{equation}
The general one is the third one, as $E_x,E_y,E_z$ are given functions of $(x,y,z)$ mapping into $\mathbb{R}$, so called components of the vector field.

The first one is just the vector field which associates to every point $P$, the vector $\vec{OP}$ ($O$ denoting the origin).

The second one is not really well defined: either $x(x,y,z)$ is the projection to the first coordinate $x$ (and so on), in which case it corresponds to the first, or $x(x,y,z)$ is meant to be a generic function, as in the third case, but the notation is very bad, so I would definitely avoid that one.

Comment: Thanks! I just came across two vector fields $\mathbf{E}=y\mathbf{\hat{x}}+x\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ and one i spherical coordinates; $\mathbf{F}= F_0(\mathbf{\hat{r}}+\mathbf{\hat{\phi}})$. How can I write them as $\mathbf{E}(argument)$ and $\mathbf{F}(argument)$? Rather confusing...

Answer (score 0):

**E** = **E**(x,y,z) means that **E** is a generic vector field whose components depend on $x, y, z$. Namely, being a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^3$, **E** has $3$ components which depend on $x, y, z$. You can denote these three components however you like. For example, if you denote them as $E_x, E_y, E_z$, then the third notation would be the correct one.

Comment: For a vector field $\mathbf{E}=y\mathbf{\hat{x}}+x\mathbf{\hat{y}}$, is it the same as number 3 above? I.e. $\mathbf{E}=\mathbf{E}(x,y,z)$, $E_x(x,y,z)=y$ and $E_y(x,y,z)=x$? Or $E_x(x,y,z)=y(x,y,z)$ and $E_y(x,y,z)=x(x,y,z)$?

Comment: The first one you said, probably, as the second wouldn't really make sense.